# Summarize text data in a field using XSLT

Tags: xslt, data-view-web-part, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to work out a way that several items in a list could be summarized in a single item if they have a keyword in common. For example, given the items:

```
Sounds: a
Sounds: b
Vocab: word
Vocab: foo
Vocab: bar
Sounds: a
```

I would return the values:

```
Sounds: a, b
Vocab: word, foo, bar
```

I have it as far as filtering out the non-unique items using

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[not(@Skill=preceding-sibling::Row/@Skill)]">
```

But I'm a bit at sea when it comes to xslt node stuff. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK I came up with a solution. It's kludgy but it works:

```
                        <xsl:template name="dvt_1">
                        <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">Table</xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[(not(@Title=preceding-sibling::Row/@Title)) and not(contains(@Title,'Sound')) and not(contains(@Title,'Vocab'))]"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="Sounds" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[contains(@Title,'Sound') and not(@Title=preceding-sibling::Row/@Title)]"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="Vocab" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[contains(@Title,'Vocab') and not(@Title=preceding-sibling::Row/@Title)]"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="soundCount" select="count($Sounds)"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="vocabCount" select="count($Vocab)"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="dvt_RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="RowLimit" select="10" />
                        <xsl:variable name="FirstRow" select="$dvt_firstrow" />
                        <xsl:variable name="LastRow" select="$FirstRow + $dvt_RowCount - 1" />
                        <xsl:variable name="IsEmpty" select="($dvt_RowCount = 0) and ($soundCount = 0) and ($vocabCount = 0)" />
                        <xsl:variable name="dvt_IsEmpty" select="($dvt_RowCount = 0) and ($soundCount = 0) and ($vocabCount = 0)"/>

                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$dvt_IsEmpty">
                                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.empty"/>
        </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
            <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                        <th class="ms-vh" width="1%" nowrap="nowrap"></th>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">Title</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="Sounds" select="$Sounds"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="soundCount" select="$soundCount"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="Vocab" select="$Vocab"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="vocabCount" select="$vocabCount"/>                    
                    <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="1" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$dvt_RowCount" />

                </xsl:call-template>
            </table>
        </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.commandfooter">
                            <xsl:with-param name="FirstRow" select="$FirstRow" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$LastRow" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="RowLimit" select="$RowLimit" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="dvt_RowCount" select="$dvt_RowCount" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="RealLastRow" select="number(ddwrt:NameChanged('',-100))" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:template>
                    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
                        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
                        <xsl:param name="FirstRow" />
                        <xsl:param name="LastRow" />
                        <xsl:param name="Sounds" />
                        <xsl:param name="soundCount" />
                        <xsl:param name="Vocab" />
                        <xsl:param name="vocabCount" />

                        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                            <xsl:variable name="dvt_KeepItemsTogether" select="false()" />
                            <xsl:variable name="dvt_HideGroupDetail" select="false()" />
                            <xsl:if test="(position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow) or $dvt_KeepItemsTogether">
                                <xsl:if test="not($dvt_HideGroupDetail)" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview" />
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:if>

                         </xsl:for-each>
                            <!--Using variables so I can push the value to something else later!-->
                            <xsl:variable name="soundgroup">
                            Sounds:
                        <xsl:for-each select="$Sounds">
                            <xsl:call-template name="soundView" />
                            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; $soundCount">, </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each> 
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:variable name="vocabgroup">
                            vocab:
                        <xsl:for-each select="$Vocab">
                            <xsl:call-template name="vocabView" />
                            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; $vocabCount">, </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each> 
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <tr><td>
```

As it stands, I need to hard code all the keywords that I want to summarize on - like I said kludgy. I feel like there is a more elegant solution to this.